# Filter script output and print it in screen while redirecting it in a file

Tags: shell-script, logs

I have created a simple shell script where I print some output messages and I invoke a really long command which generates a very long log. I redirect the log generated by the command in a file named jobLog.log using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190151/how-to-run-a-shell-script-in-the-background-and-get-no-output) answer. So my code is this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Submiting a job to ...."

sudo command_with_huge_output > jobLog.log 2>&1 && echo "Job ended! Log at jobLog.log"
```

I want to redirect one line from this log to the screen. When the job ends I use grep on the file like:

```
less jobLog.log | grep LineIwanttoFind
```

and this returns a line I am interested to print while the command is running. How can I filter the line I want, and redirect it in the screen while the command is running? Of course I also want to send the full log in jobLog.log file.

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use tee like this : `command_with_huge_output | tee jobLog.log | grep 'LineYouWantToFind'`

So all the standard output of the command_with_huge_output will go to the jobLog.log and to the pipe to grep.